# how to remove presentViewController statement without affection for the block?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I have the following code:

```
    - (void)startGameWithBlock:(void (^)(Game *))block
{
    GameViewController *gameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil];
    gameViewController.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:gameViewController animated:NO completion:^
    {
        Game *game = [[Game alloc] init];
        gameViewController.game = game;
        game.delegate = gameViewController;
        block(game);
    }];
```

}

Which allocate the GameViewController
present it, and then allocate the Game object.
Finally, it calls your block to do the game-type specific initializations

I have read about Blocks and It is fire the block after the gameviewcontroller loadView
I want the code run in the same way as it is now but with out present the view please help

Comment: Hhmm? I'm not sure that I understand your problem. Why don't you just remove the `persentViewController` part but leave the content of the completion block as it is?

Comment: I have tried this solution but it is not call the gameview controller methods

Comment: delegate of gameviewcontrller

Comment: Could you provide the code of the GameViewController? Without it it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: check this link it is my case :http://www.raywenderlich.com/12910/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-3

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not gonna read all that. Note though that if you call any delegate methods from within the gameviewcontroller's `viewDidLoad` `viewDidAppear:` etc. they will only get called if you actually **show** the vc (well that's not entirely true, you can 'hack' that, but I wouldn't recommend that). If you want them to get called without the vc being shown, you have to move those call to another method. Maybe a custom one, which you could then call when you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you simply do not want to present the `gameViewController`. So you want to do this:

```
- (void)startGameWithBlock:(void (^)(Game *))block
{
    GameViewController *gameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil];
    gameViewController.delegate = self;

    Game *game = [[Game alloc] init];
    gameViewController.game = game;
    game.delegate = gameViewController;
    block(game);
}
```

There are two issues with this.

1. As soon as you leave this function, there is no hard reference to your `gameViewController` so it would be deallocated again. You could solve this by defining a property in whatever view controller `self` refers to and assigning to that.
2. Your `block`-call could include code that depends on `gameViewController` to be shown. If this is not the case, you should be fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes I am in case two what should I do in this case should I call them manually?

Comment: Hm... So the block depends on the `gameView` to be shown? Then you have a logical issue in not showing the view but wanting to perform the block. So what, in the first place, is your motivation/explanation behind this?

Comment: I am trying to customize the code which is open source game:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/12910/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-3

Comment: also I have tracking the log and I have found dealloc<GameViewController>

Comment: I see. But apparently there is a logical inconsistency in your stated goal. (I have given you the correct answer to a flawed question, so the solution is still flawed.) So if you need help, it would be helpful if you could elaborate on what you really want to achieve by not showing the `gameView`, and why.

Comment: Yes, that was my comment 1. you have to store the reference in a property.